# Bootstrap 3 + Codeigniter Form Builder

Tags: codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap-3, formbuilder

I was looking for a PHP, Codeigniter, Bootstrap 3 form builder and couldn't find one.

Comment: You might try PHP Code Generator at [link](http://www.thephpcode.com) which generates CI application with bootstrap 3 forms and other UI elements.

Answer (score 7):

I couldn't find one that was satisfactory, so I've made one that I think is alright (and using in production now) It's located:

https://github.com/wallter/codeigniter_bootstrap_form_builder